# Activity launched from Navigation drawer not showing label and back button to parent activity

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-appbarlayout

I have created an android app with navigation drawer in MainActivity. Every thing works great in MainActivity but when i launch another activity from it, the new activity is **`not showing`** the **`back to parent activity button`** and also not showing the **`actvity label`**.

[first set of image is what i want but i'm getting second set of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys81W.png)

Manifest File:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/second_activity_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

MainActivity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Second Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="blog.tech.prasenjeet.qrhelper.HistoryActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="blog.tech.prasenjeet.qrhelper.HistoryActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/history_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just want to have title bar in my SecondActivity with its label and with a back button to MainActivity.

Any help will be appreciated!!

*And also can someone pls say how to make navigation drawer accessable from both the activity*

Please take a look at the image, you'll understand it.

Comment: Have you completed the [Implementing Effective Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html) training? It walks you through this process.

Comment: Ok!! I'll definitely go through it. Thanks for the comment. But in the mean while can anyone help me out with a quick fix. Because I know that somewhere there might be a small thing missing causing this problem :) Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what's @layout/app_bar_main in mainactivity? I suppose it's your toolbar?

Comment: Yes. Actually it has toolbar and tablayout for my fragments. That part is working completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment you include toolbar into the Main Activity with this code

```
 <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But you don't include it in your second layout!

Two solutions are possible. Either use theme with ActionBar or include toolbar manually into the second activity

And about your second question, to make navdrawer accessible from both the activities you should have fragments instead in one activity and then just replace them, so your drawer will stay accessible as it will be one activity

Answer (score 0):

The second activity has action bar is not visable.  You should include the following line in the second activity.

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

This way you will have the action bar visable.  The up button should be there. The line should be included in the parent layout.